# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError while doing bitonic sort

Tags: java, multithreading, fork-join, forkjoinpool

I wanted to implement bitonic sort using fork join model of java.So heres the code of the sorter

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class BitonicSortTask extends RecursiveAction
{
    private final int array[];
    private final int low;
    private final int high;
    private final int dir;

    public BitonicSortTask(int array[],int low,int high,int dir)
    {
        this.array = array;
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
        this.dir= dir;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute()
    {
        if(high>1)
        {
            int temp = high/2;
            BitonicSortTask left = new BitonicSortTask(array, low, temp,1);
            BitonicSortTask right = new BitonicSortTask(array, temp+1,high,0);
            invokeAll(left, right);
            BitonicMerge(array, low, high, dir);
        }
    }

    private void BitonicMerge(int[] array,int low,int high,int dir)
    {
        if(high>1)
        {
            int temp = high/2;
            for (int i=low; i<low+temp; i++)
                compAndSwap(array,i, i+temp, dir);
            BitonicMerge(array, low, temp, dir);
            BitonicMerge(array, temp+1, high, dir);
        }
    }

    private void compAndSwap(int a[],int i,int j,int dir)
    {
        if ( (a[i] > a[j] && dir == 1)||(a[i] < a[j] && dir == 0))
        {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }   
}
```

And the main (test class)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class BitonicSortTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int l=0;
        int h=999;
        int a[] = new int[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            a[i] = (int) (i*Math.round(Math.random()));
        }
        BitonicSortTask task = new BitonicSortTask(a, l, h, 1);
        ForkJoinPool fjp= new ForkJoinPool();
        fjp.invoke(task);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

But whenever i run this code i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
initialize class java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$Node
```

Could you please tell me the reason for this and how to solve it.

Comment: post your full stacktrace

Comment: When I try run this I got a `StackOverflowError`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you narrow your imports to much as the compiler doesn't warn you. To use the Fork/Join-Framework properly you have to use wildcard imports.

Your class BitonicSortTask.java needs

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

And your class BitonicSortTest.java needs

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
```

Then your program will run properly.

Comment: Wildcard imports are not required to use Java Fork/Join.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your sort algorithm is broken. This is causing a `StackOverFlowError` and because the stack is exhausted this is often being mis-reported as a `ClassDefNotFoundError`.

Your test also has a problem in it declares h=999 when it should be the size of the array to be sorted (i.e. `a.length`)

In fixing the algorithm I referred to the following examples:

- Felix Müller's [BitonicSorter.java](https://github.com/fmueller/java-playground/blob/master/bitonic-sort/src/main/java/de/cupofjava/bitonicsort/BitonicSorter.java)
- [Geeks for geeks Bitonic Sort](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitonic-sort/)
- [Wikipedia Bitonic Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitonic_sorter)

The required changes to the algorithm are simple

1. When calculating `temp` consider this the new `high` for both sides of the sort.
2. When calculating `temp` use this to calculate the new `low` in the top half of the sort.

The following class contains these fixes:

```
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

public class BitonicSortTask extends RecursiveAction {

    private final int array[];
    private final int low;
    private final int high;
    private final int dir;

    public BitonicSortTask(int array[], int low, int high, int dir) {
        this.array = array;
        this.low = low;
        this.high = high;
        this.dir = dir;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (high > 1) {
            int temp = high / 2;
            // from low, with a size of temp
            BitonicSortTask left = new BitonicSortTask(array, low, temp, 1);
            // from low + temp, with a size of temp
            BitonicSortTask right = new BitonicSortTask(array, low + temp, temp, 0);
            invokeAll(left, right);
            BitonicMerge(array, low, high, dir);
        }
    }

    private void BitonicMerge(int[] array, int low, int high, int dir) {
        if (high > 1) {
            // temp is the mid point, and also the new 'high' for both parts
            int temp = high / 2;
            for (int i = low; i < low + temp; i++) {
                compAndSwap(array, i, i + temp, dir);
            }
            // from low, with a size of temp
            BitonicMerge(array, low, temp, dir);
            // from low + temp, with a size of temp
            BitonicMerge(array, low + temp, temp, dir);
        }
    }

    private void compAndSwap(int a[], int i, int j, int dir) {
        if ((a[i] > a[j] && dir == 1) || (a[i] < a[j] && dir == 0)) {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the `Test` class. Just check the size of the array.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class BitonicSortTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[1 << 4];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            a[i] = (int) (Math.round(100 * Math.random()));
        }
        // Don't need variables for low / hi (it's just zero and array length)
        BitonicSortTask task = new BitonicSortTask(a, 0, a.length, 1);
        ForkJoinPool fjp = new ForkJoinPool();
        fjp.invoke(task);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

---

**Caveat**

This algorithm only works for arrays with a length to the power of 2. See [Bitonic sorting for n not a power of 2](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/bitonic/oddn.htm).